# Hours from inauguration

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does the phrase "Hours from inauguration" make you think that the inaugural address has been delivered hours ago? It did for me until I searched it to find that people around the world are still expecting to see it.

> WASHINGTON (AP) — **Hours from inauguration**, President-elect Joe Biden paused on what might have been his triumphal entrance to Washington Tuesday evening to mark instead the national tragedy of the coronavirus pandemic with a moment of collective grief for Americans lost.

> Source: [Associated Press](https://apnews.com/article/biden-inauguration-joe-biden-donald-trump-capitol-siege-philadelphia-aa7d5101f28c4792ccd4752795d0b968)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you are asking ELL students here, but as a native speaker, it definitely does not do so. "Hours from inauguration" means that the present time is only hours away from inauguration. Otherwise, they would have said "Only hours after inauguration..."